# Pandas: Creating column from subsetting dictionary of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with json files that come in three different flavors.

The main difference is that a few of the fields, `dmaKey` and `dmaDescription` either exist outside or inside a dictionary of one of the columns, or not at all.

For instance, this dataframe is correct in its output when converting my file from json to pandas df.

```
file_2 = [{'weekStartDate': '2019-09-02',
  'dmaKey': '803',
  'dmaDescription': 'Los Angeles',
  'scxRequiredFields': {'dmaPopulation': 5476830,
   'systemPopulation': 3810053,
   'strataMarketName': 'Los Angeles'}},
 {'weekStartDate': '2019-09-16',
  'dmaKey': '803',
  'dmaDescription': 'Los Angeles',  
  'scxRequiredFields': {'dmaPopulation': 5476830,
   'systemPopulation': 3810053,
   'strataMarketName': 'Los Angeles'}}]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(file_2)
df2
```

My two questions are how do I check if `dmaKey` and `dmaDescription` don't exist in the same file structure as above, and if that is the case, how do I go about matching the above output, and grabbing the `dmaKey` and `dmaDescription` from inside the `scxRequiredFields` dictionary column to create their own columns?

```
file_1 =[{'weekStartDate': '2020-08-17',
  'scxRequiredFields': {'dmaPopulation': 771210,
   'systemPopulation': 10407,
   'strataMarketName': 'Austin',
   'dmaKey': '635',
   'dmaDescription': 'Austin',
   'eclipseRegionName': 'TEXAS'}},
 {'weekStartDate': '2020-08-10',
  'scxRequiredFields': {'dmaPopulation': 771210,
   'systemPopulation': 10407,
   'strataMarketName': 'Austin',
   'dmaKey': '635',
   'dmaDescription': 'Austin',
   'eclipseRegionName': 'TEXAS'}}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(file_1)
df1
```

There are times where `dmaKey` and `dmaDescription` are missing entirely as well, so that is a 3rd case I'd need to factor in.

```
file_3 =[{'weekStartDate': '2020-09-17',
  'scxRequiredFields': {'dmaPopulation': 7712105432,
   'systemPopulation': 10407123,
   'strataMarketName': 'Austin',
   'eclipseRegionName': 'TEXAS'}},
 {'weekStartDate': '2020-09-10',
  'scxRequiredFields': {'dmaPopulation': 7712101234,
   'systemPopulation': 10407123,
   'strataMarketName': 'Austin',
   'eclipseRegionName': 'TEXAS'}}]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(file_3)
df3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this a matter of manipulating the data prior create a dataframe out of it.  Here's some code to perform just that:

```
def populateValues( json_file, keys ):
  for row in json_file:
    for k in ('dmaKey','dmaDescription'):
      if k not in row:
        if 'scxRequiredFields' in row:
          row[k] = row['scxRequiredFields'].get( k , defaults(row,k) )
        else:
          row[k] = defaults(row,k)
```

Here's how you might invoke that method (well, this is my test code anyway):

```
keys = ('dmaKey','dmaDescription')
for test in ( file_2, file_3, file_1 ):
  populateValues( test, keys )
  json.dump( test, sys.stdout, indent = 2 )
  print()
  print()
```

The result of calling `populateValues()` is that the data structure `test` is manipulated so that any missing keys are populated in the top level dictionary.

You haven't specified what to do if the value is completely missing from the dictionary or 'sceRequiredFields' subdictioanary.  Instead, I just called a function called `defaults(row,k)` so that the function can specify a default for given key `k` depending on anything in the row.  Here is a trivial function that just concatenates the key name with "Default":

```
def defaults( r, k ) :
  return f"Default: {k}"
```

Here's the output of test loop (I added some comments so you can see the different input file results):

```
# file_2 - no fixes required
[
  {
    "weekStartDate": "2019-09-02",
    "dmaKey": "803",
    "dmaDescription": "Los Angeles",
    "scxRequiredFields": {
      "dmaPopulation": 5476830,
      "systemPopulation": 3810053,
      "strataMarketName": "Los Angeles"
    }
  },
  {
    "weekStartDate": "2019-09-16",
    "dmaKey": "803",
    "dmaDescription": "Los Angeles",
    "scxRequiredFields": {
      "dmaPopulation": 5476830,
      "systemPopulation": 3810053,
      "strataMarketName": "Los Angeles"
    }
  }
]

# file_3 - only dumb default values get inserted
[
  {
    "weekStartDate": "2020-09-17",
    "scxRequiredFields": {
      "dmaPopulation": 7712105432,
      "systemPopulation": 10407123,
      "strataMarketName": "Austin",
      "eclipseRegionName": "TEXAS"
    },
    "dmaKey": "Default: dmaKey",
    "dmaDescription": "Default: dmaDescription"
  },
  {
    "weekStartDate": "2020-09-10",
    "scxRequiredFields": {
      "dmaPopulation": 7712101234,
      "systemPopulation": 10407123,
      "strataMarketName": "Austin",
      "eclipseRegionName": "TEXAS"
    },
    "dmaKey": "Default: dmaKey",
    "dmaDescription": "Default: dmaDescription"
  }
]

# file_1 - Values are taken from scxRequiredFields
[
  {
    "weekStartDate": "2020-08-17",
    "scxRequiredFields": {
      "dmaPopulation": 771210,
      "systemPopulation": 10407,
      "strataMarketName": "Austin",
      "dmaKey": "635",
      "dmaDescription": "Austin",
      "eclipseRegionName": "TEXAS"
    },
    "dmaKey": "635",
    "dmaDescription": "Austin"
  },
  {
    "weekStartDate": "2020-08-10",
    "scxRequiredFields": {
      "dmaPopulation": 771210,
      "systemPopulation": 10407,
      "strataMarketName": "Austin",
      "dmaKey": "635",
      "dmaDescription": "Austin",
      "eclipseRegionName": "TEXAS"
    },
    "dmaKey": "635",
    "dmaDescription": "Austin"
  }
]
```